# selectedSegmentIndex always returning 0

Tags: objective-c

I am building a Rock Paper Scissors game and I am trying to implement a system where there will never be a tie. My current system is

```
if (userSelection == 0)
    computerPick =[self computerGenerateResponce];
    if (computerPick == 0)
        while (computerPick == 0)
            computerPick = [self computerGenerateResponce];
```

Is there a better way to implement this system? This works, but seems a little bit clunky.

Comment: Please change the title of this question.  What does it have to do with `selectedSegmentIndex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum, you can eliminate the if(computerPick == 0) level, since that is the first thing that while(computerPick == 0) does. This will not affect your algorithm at all. Then, you can probably consolidate the call into the condition check, and further, you can just use implicit boolean casting:

```
if (!userSelection)
    while(! (computerPick = [self computerGenerateResponce]))
```

This will essentially just keep assigning a new pick to computerPick until it is not zero.